# How to have an exposed static constant member in F#?

Tags: c#, f#

I'm attempting to convert the following code from C# to F#:

```
public class MyType
{
    public const short N_CONST = 8;
}
```

It is currently used as a constant in the following snippet:

```
new byte[MyType.N_CONST] { 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8 };
```

(only a constant is legal in this context).

In attempting to convert this, I've come up with two possibilities:

1. `static let`

   ```
   type MyType =
       [<Literal>] 
       static let N_CONST = 8s
   ```

   This fails to compile in the consuming code, as `N_CONST` is not exposed.
2. `static member val`

   ```
   type MyType =
       [<Literal>]
       static member val  N_CONST = 8
   ```

   This fails to compile at the definition, disallowing the `[<Literal>]`.

(How) can I support the consuming code?